# Position parameter in add_menu_page() function of WordPress

Tags: php, wordpress, function, parameters, position

I am learning WordPress CMS, now I am building my own Custom theme, and I am using `add_menu_page()` function to create a menu stroke for my theme on admin page. For *Position* parameter I used a number higher than 99, for ex. 110, but what if my user has another plugin or theme which uses the same number for position? Will they both work correctly?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Yes they will work correctly it's only the position of the menu that changes.

Comment: Thanks Andrew Schultz.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It will work correctly, the position of your menu item and menu item of that plugin depends of how early they were declared in the code.

If your plugin and "that plugin" add the add_menu_page() function on the same WordPress hook, in that case the position will depend on the hook priority (the third parameter of add_action() function).

Comment: Thanks Misha Rudrastyh.

Comment: I'm glad to help :)